# SQL query with 2 sub query condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Master table:

```
MasterID | PartID  
1          1  
2          3  
3          5
```

Part table:

```
PartID | PartName | DeleteDate  
1        Part1      NULL  
2        Part2      NULL  
4        Part4      NULL  
5        Part5      08-04-2017
```

Result table:

```
MasterID | PartID  
2          3  
3          5
```

These two tables are present in two different database and i need to validate with a SQL query to fetch the record if Master table has `PartID` that are not in Part table and Master table has any `PartID` that are deleted in Part table (i.e. `DeleteDate` IS NOT NULL)

I'm trying with a below query, but not getting the expected results

```
Select  
    *  
FROM DBNAME.DBO.Master  
Where PartID in (  
    Select  
        PartID   
     from Part)   
and PartID not in (  
    Select   
        PartID   
    from Part   
    where DeleteDate is NOT NULL)
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this

Comment: When posting code or things that should be in monospace font, select what you pasted, and press the {} button, keeps it readable for us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to `LEFT JOIN` the `Master` table to the `Part` table and then retain any parts which either did not map to anything in the `Part` table, or mapped to a deleted part.

```
SELECT
    m.PartID,
    CASE WHEN p.partID IS NULL THEN 'missing' ELSE 'deleted' END AS status
FROM Master m
LEFT JOIN Part p
    ON m.PartID = p.PartID
WHERE
    p.PartID IS NULL OR         -- missing part
    p.DeleteDate IS NOT NULL    -- deleted (but present) part
```

Comment: You'll get an error wih that one due to unaliased partied in select list

Comment: Oh, you just fixed it :)

Comment: After a few thousand SQL questions it gets easier to detect such errors.

Comment: Maybe adding `CASE WHEN p.Partid IS NULL then 'missing' ELSE 'deleted' END as status`would make the results more useful too

Comment: I'm sure we'll overtake Gordon Linoff one day.. :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Gordon is sort of like those agents in the Matrix movies.  It is possible to take them down, but only by bringing down the entire system :-)

Comment: I'm sure Gordon Linoff sidelines as Petyr Baelish/Littlefinger from Game of Thrones :)  How he manages to fit it all in I've no idea, maybe he has his employees log in using his ID; but the rate he's going we're going to have to find/replace JonSkeet/GordonLinoff in the Chuck Norris facts thread..

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can use union for two cases

```
Select 
       t1.* 
From 
       DBNAME.DBO.Master t1,Part t2
Where 
       t1.PartID = t2.PartID(+) and t2.PartID is null
Union All
Select 
       t1.* 
From 
       DBNAME.DBO.Master t1,Part t2
Where 
       t1.PartID = t2.PartID and t2.DeleteDate is not null;
```